# Topic doesn't exist as expected in kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

After running this command :

**`bin/kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:6666, localhost:6667, localhost:6668, localhost:6669`**

Output - Test

```
After running this command :
```

> **`bin/kafka-topics.bat --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:6666, localhost:6667, localhost:6668, localhost:6669  --topic Test`**

Error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic 'Test' does not exist as expected
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.kafka$admin$TopicCommand$$ensureTopicExists(TopicCommand.scala:523)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.describeTopic(TopicCommand.scala:301)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:68)
at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)

```
Can anybody help me in solving this issue?
```

Comment: You have to either create the topic beforehand, or you can configure Kafka to autocreate topics.

Comment: @daniu I have already created topic

Answer (score 2):

Topic names are stored in zookeeper along with topic metadata, leader for each partition in the topic etc.

In your case it looks like zookeeper has this information, but maybe kafka data is either corrupt or deleted.

Stop kafka, zookeeper, remove your zookeeper data directory, kafka data directory and start both the services again.

Recreate your topic, it should work fine.

Comment: Actually I have created 4 host but replication factor is 3, Thats why it was not showing topic. Thanks Suhas NM

Comment: I don't see a relationship between topic being visible and replication factor.

Comment: You cannot define replication factor greater than number of brokers.

Comment: Yeah, but you have 4 brokers and your replication factor is 3

Comment: Yes, that topic is created on only 3 brokers and i was checking with all 4 brokers. Out of 4 brokers, 1 broker doesn't have that topic. So it was showing this topic doesn't exist( with all 4 brokers).

Comment: No, Kafka doesn't work that way, your topic information is stored in zookeeper and you should be able to produce/consume for all the nodes irrespective of replication factor and whether that node contains data for partitions in the specified topic

Comment: But if I have 4 brokers and rep factor is 3, then data will replicate only on 3 brokers, data wont replicate on remaining one.

Comment: Yes, the data will replicate on all brokers. You're probably thinking of consumers; if you had 4 of those, one will receive no messages for that topic.

Comment: Yes, you should still be able to consume/produce data by connecting to any of the brokers, it is abstracted to users.

Comment: No, I am not thinking of consumer. I just want to describe the topic but when I am describing using all servers, it gives me error and when I removed one server, it successfully described me topic

Answer (score 1):

I got the 'topic does not exist as expected error' when I tried to delete the topic and it said 'topic already exists' when I try to create the topic. Deleting the topic directory in kafka/data solved the problem for me. That way I didn't have to loose any data either. I didn't have to delete zookeeper data or kafka data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have created 4 brokers and replication factor is 3 and I was checking for all brokers. Thats why it was not showing topic. When I checked it for 3 brokers, it gives me correct information and does not give any error.

Comment: I don't understand, why 3 replicas with 4 broker would cause any problem?